# Doctrine2: Many-to-Many from Object X to Object X

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

i try to set up a "following" feature for users, so users can follow users.

I tried doing this by adding a Many-to-many Relation:

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User",inversedBy="User",fetch="LAZY",cascade={"persist"})
@ORM\JoinTable=(name="user_followers",
joinColumns={
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="follower_id",referencedColumnName="id")}
)
```

Now doctrine creates a table user_user with just one field user_id.

I really have no idea how to declare this.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I was interested with in the same question (why does the auto-generated jointable has only one field when self referencing in many-to-many?). Your answer below doesn't help me understand that, because it's just a workaround (thought it's given by the official doc). Any other clue?

Comment: @Ninj: sry, but no. I haven't found any other solutions yet either :(

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's another flaw in the Doctrine Generator. This tool is far from complete. Thanks for answering however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution myself.

You can actually use a self refferencing Many-to-Many Solution. From the Doctrine Website:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     */
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing